# Laravel firstOrCreate with relationships not returning a model instance

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using firstOrCreate() to find the first invoice or create it.
This code was working last week then all of a sudden stopped working.

What is working:
A database entry IS generated & there are no errors.

The problem: firstOrCreate returning empty. `{}`

The code:

```
$invoice = Invoice::firstOrCreate(
            [
                'user' => $user->id,
                'package' => $package->id,
                'term' => $pricing->term,
                'paid' => 0
            ], [
                'amount' => $pricing->price,
                'hash' => 'omittedforSO',
                'coupon' => null
            ]
)->with(['billingInfo', 'package', 'price', 'coupon']);
```

Comment: Are you saying that $invoice is {} or that Invoice::firstOrCreate(...) is empty? Also is empty an empty model or a null or something else?

Comment: When it returns empty? Whether `firstOrCreate` finds the match or while inserting a new row !?

Comment: @luminoslty show us your migration, model and the complete controller function. You are surely missing something around.

Comment: @ElishaSenoo the entire controller function is that + return response, I fixed the issue by moving with before firstOrCreate. Furthermore, I verified the model & migration was correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `with()` before `firstOrCreate()`

```
$invoice = Invoice::with(['billingInfo', 'package', 'price', 'coupon'])->firstOrCreate(
        [
            'user' => $user->id,
            'package' => $package->id,
            'term' => $pricing->term,
            'paid' => 0
        ], [
            'amount' => $pricing->price,
            'hash' => 'notforSO',
            'coupon' => null
        ]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [firstOrCreate](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_firstOrCreate) and your eager loading, he should either find and return the first model of `Invoice` where the arguments (first array) match with extra attributes as arrays, containing the relationships you've written, or create an `Invoice` with the values of your second argument.

Having that said, it shouldn't return an empty array, ever, unless you've edited Laravel's core code. If you var_dump (`dd`) that result (`$invoice`), it will either give you a Querybuilder or an Eloquent model (with its list of attributes with null values).

Make sure your fields are in the fillable array of the model `Invoice`

Comment: Every model has their fillable arrays set properly & I have not made any core changes to laravel. I'll update the post with a var_dump